# PHP DateTime support enabled, but page dies

Tags: php, datetime

I am running a site on a server using php 5.5.10, and trying to use the DateTime object. Anytime I use it the page comes up blank, with no errors in the httpd log.

I ran php info, and it says that Date is enabled:

```
date

date/time support   enabled
"Olson" Timezone Database Version   0.system
Timezone Database   internal
Default timezone    UTC

Directive   Local Value Master Value
 date.default_latitude  31.7667 31.7667
date.default_longitude  35.2333 35.2333
date.sunrise_zenith 90.583333   90.583333
date.sunset_zenith  90.583333   90.583333
date.timezone   UTC UTC
```

Does anyone have any ideas as to what I can do here?

On my local dev server I am running php 5.4.9 and having no problem with it.

Thanks!

Edit: Here is the code

```
//set date to first of month in order to ease month calculations
$today = new DateTime();
$today->setDate(date('Y'), date('m'), 1);
$interval = new DateInterval('P1M');
```

Comment: Show us the code, have you set your timezone in php.ini?

Comment: Check the phpinfo for where the PHP error log actually is (error_log variable) as it may not be where you think. Make sure error_reporting is set correctly and log_errors is turned on. Then hopefully you will find some more helpful error messages in the log!

Comment: I have set the timezone in php.ini - see it listed above. I'm going to add the code.

Answer (score 1):

If you are using namespaces, be sure that when creating a new DateTime object you call it globally.

```
$today = new \DateTime();
$today->setDate(date('Y'), date('m'), 1);
$interval = new \DateInterval('P1M');
```